# how to get userid in membership?

Tags: asp.net-membership

i know how to get userid for a current user

```
 MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
 Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

But for my application i need to get userid of user who are not loginned in also.
Because i need to assign the userid to different table which i m using.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Membership.GetUser(username, userIsOnline)` method, passing **false** as the userIsOnline parameter.

Comment: Ok, technophile gave you what you need but let me be a bit more explicit, if necessary to get you where you need to be...
`var userId = (Guid)(Membership.GetUser(username,false).ProviderUserKey);`